# Fixed Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar, center, css-position

I have a navigation bar that I want to keep fixed and centered. I have the bar currently centered, but when I add the 'position: fixed' It moved my navigation bar all the way over to the left of the screen. My navigation bar is currently about 20% from the top of the screen (centered).

CSS:

```
div.social-wrap{
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="social-wrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="link_home shadow extend">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="link_identity shadow extend">Identity</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="books.html" class="link_books shadow extend">Books</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="link_contact shadow extend">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Christdentity" class="link_twitter shadow extend" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sederu/uPZuu/

Comment: What do you mean by keep fixed? Fixed width?

Comment: sorry, it's position. So it doesn't move up when you scroll but stays in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` is shifting when using fixed positioning, because, by default [its taken out of the document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) and becomes relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (other than static) .. in your case thats probably the root `<html>` element if you don't have any other positioned ancestors for your navigation bar. This makes sense if its shifting to the top left corner of your viewport.

You basically need to set the left property to 50% to center and also need to set the margin-left to the negative half of the div's width to shift the center towards the middle of the div.

Example:

```
div.social-wrap{
width: 500px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it but it moved the nav bar all the way to the bottom of the screen and crammed into the left corner.

Comment: I see .. please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so I can help you better ..

Comment: You just had the properties mixed up, here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPZuu/2/

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I appreciate your determination to helm me solve this problem!